# Wordpress Frontend Ajax with wp_localize_script Error: ajaxurl is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, frontend

I'm trying to create markers on a map via ajax on a wp theme.
After some struggle I found out that I can't use any php file to get data via ajax, I have to use the admin-ajax.php file.

Accordingly to many examples, this is my code

in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file' );
function add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file()
{
   wp_localize_script( 'frontend_ajax', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_custom_script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/ajax-javascript.js', array('jquery') );

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_post_information', 'get_post_information' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_information', 'get_post_information' );


function get_post_information() 
{ 

$get_this= $_GET['this'];
$get_that= $_GET['that'];

...my select...

echo json formatted data
}
```

The js file is loaded and working, it does other stuff before the ajax call, where it stops for an error in this line:

```
$.post({ 
        url:frontendajax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'get_post_information',
            data: data
        },
        success: function(response) {
```

But I always Have the same error:

**Reference Error: frontendajax.ajaxurl is not defined**

where is my error?

PS: I use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() because I am in a child theme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [`wp_localize_script` docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

> IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called **after** the script it's being attached to has been registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script().

And the *handle* must be the same:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_custom_script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/ajax-javascript.js', array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'ajax_custom_script', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize I needed to use the same handle! To make it work I also had to pass the name of the action function along with data (I updated my question)

Comment: The placement of the script is something that was causing me issues. This is the right answer!

Comment: Bing! That was totally my problem. I had the wp_enqueue_script() and wp_localize_script() in the function, but in the wrong order. Swapping them totally fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks for this! I couldn't figure it out at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create markers on a map via ajax on a wp theme. After some struggle I found out that I can't use any php file to get data via ajax, I have to use the admin-ajax.php file.

admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
});
?>

Comment: I really suggest you to carefully read WP Ajax docs https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
I know it's a bit confusing at first sight, here you can find a real world example https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/